# Regular expression to match beginning and end of a line?

Tags: regex, bash, sed, end-of-line, start-of-line

Could anyone tell me a regex that matches the beginning or end of a line? e.g. if I used `sed 's/[regex]/"/g' filehere` the output would be each line in quotes? I tried `[\^$]` and `[\^\n]` but neither of them seemed to work. I'm probably missing something obvious, I'm new to these

Comment: Please use all the necessary tags in your question(s). Regex is a broad term.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
sed -e 's/^/"/' -e 's/$/"/' file
```

Comment: No need for the "g"s as neither the start nor the end of a line appear multiple times on a line.

Answer (score 3):

To add quotes to the start and end of every line is simply:

```
sed 's/.*/"&"/g'
```

The RE you were trying to come up with to match the start or end of each line, though, is:

```
sed -r 's/^|$/"/g'
```

Its an ERE (enable by "-r") so it will work with GNU sed but not older seds.

Answer (score 0):

matthias's response is perfectly adequate, but you could also use a backreference to do this.  if you're learning regular expressions, they are a handy thing to know.

here's how that would be done using a backreference:

```
sed 's/\(^.*$\)/"\1"/g' file
```

at the heart of that regex is `^.*$`, which means match anything (`.*`) surrounded by the start of the line (`^`) and the end of the line (`$`), which effectively means that it will match the whole line every time.

putting that term inside parenthesis creates a backreference that we can refer to later on (in the replace pattern).  but for sed to realize that you mean to create a backreference instead of matching literal parentheses, you have to escape them with backslashes.  thus, we end up with `\(^.*$\)` as our search pattern.

the replace pattern is simply a double quote followed by `\1`, which is our backreference (refers back to the first pattern match enclosed in parentheses, hence the 1).  then add your last double quote to end up with `"\1"`.

Comment: ^.*$ is the same as .*, the ^ and the $ are redundant. You also don't need to backreference a specific matching string when the whole RE matches - that's what & is for.

Comment: agreed, but i threw them in there for the sake of clarity.  my answer was more intended to show how to use a backreference rather than how to address the specific scenario in question.

Comment: that's fine but it would have been useful to also show the OP the answer to his specific question so he doesn't think this is the best way to do that.